# Vue Router - beforeDestroy is called for parent component when children route changes

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I have my routes defined like this

```
{
path: '/menu',
component: () => import('./Menu.vue'),
children: [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: () => import('./menus-admin/MenusAdmin.vue'),
    name: 'menusAdmin'
  },
  {
    path: 'import',
    component: () => import('./menus-admin/menus-import/MenusImport.vue'),
    name: 'menusImport'
  }
 ]
}
```

When I navigate between the `admin` and `import` routes using `router-link` components, the parent `Menu.vue` component gets destroyed and created again. I would expect the `Menu.vue` component to no bet destroyed unless I navigate to a completely different route. This is a problem because I have implemented some lifecycle hooks that I don't want to be called over and over when the child routes change.
Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug or is it a feature?

Comment: I can't replicate this ~ http://jsfiddle.net/jgo7dxqr/. The parent component is not destroyed when navigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. My `<router-view>` had `:key="$route.fullPath"` on it. That was forcing it to re-render everything on every route change.

Removed that and it worked as expected.